# How to push an open graph object on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I have an application with a open graph actions validated that I use with my site. I would like to publish these actions on a facebook page rather than on the user timeline.
Here is the request that I use:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/{my page id}/my-app:post?access_token={page access token}&action=http://mywebsite/myaction
```

The Facebook API returns me this error:

```
["message"]=>string(30) "An unknown error has occurred."
["type"]=>string(14) "OAuthException"
```

Is this normal? Is it possible to publish open graph action on a fan page?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to publish open graph action on a fan page ?

Actions are supposed to be undertaken by real people.

Having a *page* „watch a movie” or „cook a recipe” etc. wouldn’t make much sense at all.

Comment: +1 Pages cannot 'use' OG apps, nor can OG actions be posted to a page's timeline